# Zero Mean assumption in theory but not in practice?

Tags: mean, regularization, covariance-matrix, graphical-model, time-varying-covariate

The paper "Network Inference via the Time-Varying Graphical Lasso" by David Hallac, Youngsuk Park, Stephen Boyd, Jure Leskovec shows how a (time varying) covariance matrix can be shrunk in order to reduce covariates conditional dependence. One of the main assumptions on the covariates matrix is that it is $\pmb{\mu=0,\Sigma}$ distributed. Then in same paper, the example in section 7.1 - "Applications in Financial Data" does not satisfy this assumption: daily stock prices do not have zero mean ($\pmb{\mu\neq0,\Sigma}$). How can this be explained?

Comment: Zero mean is an assumption about noise, daily stock prices are noisy but are not just noise. Even 'true' noise would be observed as a non-zero mean as in the real world noise never perfectly cancels out. Any method of cancelling out time based covariance will capture the type of process they are designed to and not others, leaving non-zero biases.

Comment: Then why they don't explicitly assume the noise to be zero-mean distributed? To me it seems that the assumption is on the random variable X